# How to take values of each key from a json and plot it as a graph in python

Tags: python, json, dataframe, visualization

I have created a list of possible keys as

```
param=["n_neighbors", "window_size","weighted","p","max_depth","grace_period","_max_size","l2"]
```

I loaded the json into a dataframe df1

```
df1=pd.read_json("population_steps.json")
```

On executing the below line

```
df1[0][0]['Classifier'][1]
```

I got this as output:

```
{'n_neighbors': 20, 'window_size': 500, 'weighted': True, 'p': 2}
```

and similarly for the below line:

```
df1[1][0]['Classifier'][1]
```

I got this output:

```
{'max_depth': 60, 'grace_period': 10, '_max_size': 5}
```

I have 10 columns and 1000 rows in df1.

I have to plot values for each of the value in param. for example a graph for max_depth with the row number in x-axis and the value 60 in y-axis.

PFB the output for df1.head()

```
     0  \
0  {'Scaler': 'MinMaxScaler', 'Classifier': ['KNN...   
1  {'Scaler': 'MinMaxScaler', 'Classifier': ['Hoe...   
2  {'Scaler': 'MinMaxScaler', 'Classifier': ['Hoe...   
3  {'Scaler': 'MinMaxScaler', 'Classifier': ['Hoe...   
4  {'Scaler': 'MinMaxScaler', 'Classifier': ['Hoe...   

                                                   1  \
0  {'Scaler': 'StandardScaler', 'Classifier': ['H...   
1  {'Scaler': 'StandardScaler', 'Classifier': ['H...   
2  {'Scaler': 'StandardScaler', 'Classifier': ['H...   
3  {'Scaler': 'StandardScaler', 'Classifier': ['H...   
4  {'Scaler': 'StandardScaler', 'Classifier': ['H...   

                                                   2  \
0  {'Scaler': 'MinMaxScaler', 'Classifier': ['Hoe...   
1  {'Scaler': 'MinMaxScaler', 'Classifier': ['Hoe...   
2  {'Scaler': 'MinMaxScaler', 'Classifier': ['Hoe...   
3  {'Scaler': 'MinMaxScaler', 'Classifier': ['Hoe...   
4  {'Scaler': 'MinMaxScaler', 'Classifier': ['Hoe...   

                                                   3  \
0  {'Scaler': 'MinMaxScaler', 'Classifier': ['KNN...   
1  {'Scaler': 'MinMaxScaler', 'Classifier': ['KNN...   
2  {'Scaler': 'MinMaxScaler', 'Classifier': ['KNN...   
3  {'Scaler': 'MinMaxScaler', 'Classifier': ['KNN...   
4  {'Scaler': 'MinMaxScaler', 'Classifier': ['Hoe...   

                                                   4  \
0  {'Scaler': 'MaxAbsScaler', 'Classifier': ['KNN...   
1  {'Scaler': 'MaxAbsScaler', 'Classifier': ['KNN...   
2  {'Scaler': 'MaxAbsScaler', 'Classifier': ['KNN...   
3  {'Scaler': 'MinMaxScaler', 'Classifier': ['Hoe...   
4  {'Scaler': 'MinMaxScaler', 'Classifier': ['Hoe...   

                                                   5  \
0  {'Scaler': 'MinMaxScaler', 'Classifier': ['KNN...   
1  {'Scaler': 'MinMaxScaler', 'Classifier': ['KNN...   
2  {'Scaler': 'MinMaxScaler', 'Classifier': ['KNN...   
3  {'Scaler': 'MinMaxScaler', 'Classifier': ['KNN...   
4  {'Scaler': 'MinMaxScaler', 'Classifier': ['KNN...   

                                                   6  \
0  {'Scaler': 'MaxAbsScaler', 'Classifier': ['KNN...   
1  {'Scaler': 'MaxAbsScaler', 'Classifier': ['KNN...   
2  {'Scaler': 'MinMaxScaler', 'Classifier': ['Hoe...   
3  {'Scaler': 'MinMaxScaler', 'Classifier': ['Hoe...   
4  {'Scaler': 'MinMaxScaler', 'Classifier': ['Hoe...   

                                                   7  \
0  {'Scaler': 'StandardScaler', 'Classifier': ['K...   
1  {'Scaler': 'StandardScaler', 'Classifier': ['K...   
2  {'Scaler': 'StandardScaler', 'Classifier': ['K...   
3  {'Scaler': 'StandardScaler', 'Classifier': ['K...   
4  {'Scaler': 'StandardScaler', 'Classifier': ['K...   

                                                   8  \
0  {'Scaler': 'MaxAbsScaler', 'Classifier': ['Hoe...   
1  {'Scaler': 'MaxAbsScaler', 'Classifier': ['Hoe...   
2  {'Scaler': 'MaxAbsScaler', 'Classifier': ['Hoe...   
3  {'Scaler': 'MaxAbsScaler', 'Classifier': ['Hoe...   
4  {'Scaler': 'MaxAbsScaler', 'Classifier': ['Hoe...   

                                                   9  
0  {'Scaler': 'MaxAbsScaler', 'Classifier': ['Hoe...  
1  {'Scaler': 'MaxAbsScaler', 'Classifier': ['Hoe...  
2  {'Scaler': 'MaxAbsScaler', 'Classifier': ['Hoe...  
3  {'Scaler': 'MaxAbsScaler', 'Classifier': ['Hoe...  
4  {'Scaler': 'MaxAbsScaler', 'Classifier': ['Hoe...
```

For better understanding find the screenshot of the df below.

[image]

Comment: use `print(df1.head())` and paste output to the question please.

Comment: Please find the updated question

Comment: Does it work to convert json objects to rows and columns?

Comment: yes, when I do this df1=pd.read_json("population_steps.json"). It gives me the dataframe.

Comment: sorry, it is not clear. Can you add an expected output ? or can you write more detailed ?